# Firefox for Android Send to Device stopped arriving at Firefox on my laptop

Tags: firefox, sync

This is the Firefox for Android feature where you click "Share", "Send to Other Devices" and the tab appears the next time you open Firefox on your laptop.

When the new Firefox Sync came out, it told me I would have to remove my account from the old Firefox Sync. I did so by following [these instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-update-new-sync?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=how-to-update-to-the-new-firefox-sync) to unlink my devices and sign in. My bookmark sync is working fine, but sending from my phone Firefox to my desktop is broken. When I tap the little paper airplane to share to a device, it still pops up my computer name, and still says "Your tab was sent!" afterwards. But it never shows up as a new tab on my computer the way it did before.

Both my Firefoxes are up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're sending the tabs to the right device? As there's no maintenance site for these, it's easy to have old device entries in your list which are no longer connected to a physical device. I also commonly have stale duplicate device entries (e.g. when I reinstall the OS of a phone without remembering to disconnect Sync first).

I would try renaming the "desktop" device in Sync and confirming that the new device name shows up on the mobile.

If not, you know you have a setup issue on the desktop. If the new name does show up on the mobile, then it's something else.

Comment: The new name did show up when I renamed the device. That step also fixed the problem. So thanks!